# iOS location services: CLLocation's timestamp issue

Tags: ios, time, cllocationmanager, utc, cllocation

I'm developing an iOS 7+ app that needs to get accurate location updates and their timestamp, in order to know the time when a user reaches certain locations. The problem is that the `timestamp` property of the `CLLocation` objects received in the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method seem to depend on the time settings of the device, they aren't universal times. So, since a user can "fake" the time of her device, I can't rely on that information.

ASFAIK, it is possible in `Android` apps to get the NMEA data from GPS and then get the universal time of positions, but I can´t find that in iOS. Is there any alternative to solve this problem in iOS apps?

**EDIT:** related to this issue: is it possible to detect if the user changes her device's timezone, date or time while the app is running, even in the background?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get true GEO timestamp from iDevice I think you should call a Time API. Recommend Google Time API.
Just submit device's GPS and the local timestamp the API will return timezone, rawOffset, daylight time saving etc... So you can calculate correct device's date time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking the `Google Time Zone API` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/) and their usage limits doesn't seem to be much wide for apps than could reach a certain volume of users...